# Using Fitting's decomposition theorem on modules directly in calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, modules, matrix-decomposition

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ be a vector space with standard basis. Given a linear map $A\in End(V)$. Fitting's theorem says that there exists a unique reduction $V=N\oplus R $ for which $A|_N\in End(N)$ is nilpotent and $A|_R\in End(R)$ is invertible. I'm following this far, but if we where to apply this to an example, let $A$ be represented by the matrix $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
    1   &   1   &   0 \\
    0   &   1   &   1 \\
    0   &   0   &   0
\end{array}\right)$. How would one determine $N,R,A|_R,A|_N$? I guess that $N,R$ is of lower dimension than $dim(V)=3$, and hence $A|_R,A|_N$ would not be a square matrix, or am I all wrong? Is it then even possible to explicitly determine $A|_R,A|_N$?

Text on Fittings theorem: https://planetmath.org/fittingslemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $V=\mathbb R^3$ instead of $\mathbb R$, otherwise the vector space is one-dimensional and $A$ is represented not by a $3\times3$ matrix but by a $1\times1$ matrix.

In general, suppose $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $\ker(A^m)=\ker(A^{m+1})$. Then $N=\ker(A^m)$ and $R=\operatorname{range}(A^m)$. If you don't want to calculate $m$, it is also guaranteed that $N=\ker(A^n)$ and $R=\operatorname{range}(A^n)$ because $m\le n$. In your case, $m$ is obviously equal to $1$. Therefore $N=\ker(A)=\operatorname{span}\{(1,-1,1)^T\}$ and $R=\operatorname{range}(A)=\{(x,y,0)^T:x,y\in\mathbb R\}$. It follows that $A|_N=0$ and $A|_R$ is represented by the matrix $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ with respect to the ordered basis $\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T\}$.

Comment: You are correct in assuming that I meant $V=\mathbb{R}$. As far as I understand the index of nilpotency is the smallest $k$ s.t. the matrix $B^k=0$. But given the $A$ defined above we do in particular have that $A^1 \neq 0$. As far as I can see $A$ is not nilpotent in it self. Especially we have $A^3=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
     1 & 3 & 2  \\
     0 & 1 & 1 \\
     0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right) \neq 0 $. It could be nice if you could clarify :)

Comment: @slowpoke Oh, I meant the index of nilpotency of the nilpotent part of $A$. Edited now.

Comment: Thank you. And once again I mean $V=\mathbb{R}^3$... How did you find the span of $N,R$?

Comment: Is it is because: for $v_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
     1  \\
     0 \\
     0
\end{array}\right)$ and $v_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
     0  \\
     1 \\
     0
\end{array}\right)$ you can write $v_3=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
     1  \\
     1 \\
     0
\end{array}\right)$ as $v_1+v_2$? And hence the image must be a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$. Especially we get that $dim(Im(A))=2$, hence we need to have $dim(ker(A))=1$. After that you see that $w=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
     1  \\
     -1 \\
     1
\end{array}\right)$ ($dim(w)=1$) satisfy $Aw=0$.

Comment: @slowpoke $N$ and $R$ are found by simple inspection. Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. We have $Ae_1=e_1,\,Ae_3=e_2$ and $A(e_1-e_2+e_3)=0$. Hence $\operatorname{range}(A)$ is the linear span of $e_1$ and $e_2$, and $\ker(A)=e_1-e_2+e_3$.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Now we only have to convince ourselves that $A|_N=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 &   1 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right)|_{span\{ e_1, e_2\} } = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1
\end{array}\right) 
$. And that $A|_R=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 1 &   1 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}\right)|_{span\{ \left( \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
    1
\end{array}\right) \} } = 0
$. But I feel like we need another augment here. Why is this true?

Comment: @slowpoke It's trivial to check that $A(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\times \{0\})=\mathbb R\times \mathbb R \times \{0\}$, and so (as a surjective endomorphism of two-dimensional spaces, $A$ is an isomorphism on $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times \{0\}$. As for the other submodule, it is exactly the kernel, so of course it acts nilpotently on it (it is uniformly zero after one application!). What more is needed?  Nothing I think...